# Time Complexity And Space Complexity Of This Code?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the Time & Space Complexity of this code ?

Here,is the code for moving all the negative elements of any array to the end of the array while maintaining the order of all non-negative elements as well as negative elements - as,

Input : {-11,-1,3, 24, -7, -5, 11, -6}

Output : {3, 24, 11, -11, -1, -7, -5, -6}

```
public static void MoveNegativeElementsToEnd(int arr[])
    {
        int k=arr.length-1;
        int n=arr.length;

        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(arr[i]<0){
                for(int j=i;j<k;j++){
                    swap(arr,j,j+1);
                }
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void swap(int[] arr, int a, int b){
        int temp=arr[a];
        arr[a]=arr[b];
        arr[b]=temp;
    }
```

Acco. to me, time complexity is O(N^2),

n -> for traversing the array

n -> for swapping the negative elements to the end each time.
Is this correct ?

And is the space complexity is O(1) as, for all the inputs it takes the same no. of variables ?

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and how is it supposed to work?

Comment: Move all negative elements of the array to the end.

Comment: Yes, time and space complexity is as you say.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as the classic nested loops making `n * n`, because of the `k`. It is still O(n^2), but you should try to think of a family of inputs that it's O(n^2) on.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop runs for `n-1-i` times (when it runs). Assuming the probability `p` of an array element to be negative, every element contributes `p(n-1-i)` swaps. Now you sum this for `i` in `[n-1, 0]`, i.e. `n-1-i` in `[0, n-1]`, and the expected cost is

```
p(n-1)n/2
```

swaps.